# How can I fix/reset my MIDI setup?

Tags: midi, logic-pro

I had an Axiom-49 MIDI controller plugged into my Mac with a MIDI to USB cable, and everything was working great. I was trying to add a Roland digital drum kit into the setup and plugged its MIDI out into the Axiom's MIDI in.

Everything promptly went to hell. I've since unplugged that and turned everything off and on, but now only four of the keys on the keyboard work (make a sound in Logic): the top G#, A, A#, and B (only in the top octave on the physical keyboard).

I've tried plugging another controller in (an M-Audio Keystation) and it produces no sound either, so the problem is ... in Logic? In the computer's MIDI configuration? Help!

Comment: I guess "went to hell" is not meant literally, but what exactly *do* you mean with that? Can you try a different computer?

Comment: So, yeah ... the keyboard has 4 octaves of keys, and only four of them produce sound: G#, A, A#, and B. When the transpose buttons work normally, shifting the notes these keys produce up or down, but not changing which physical keys work. Also the 8 drum pads on the controller create sound.

I don't have another computer to plug into to see what would happen, unfortunately.

Comment: This sounds as if the Axiom keys have been split into zones; or it could be a hardware problem.

Comment: Hmm, except that it started the moment I plugged the other thing into the Axiom's MIDI in, @CL. And that the Keystation's midi signal is also not getting through. Very weird, and I don't know where to start with troubleshooting

Comment: Do you plug the Keystation into the Axiom or directly into the Mac's USB? In the first case, it's likely that plugging the drum kit somehow fried lots of the Axiom's electronics.

Comment: I don't know the Axion controller, but I used a Korg Tactile-Controller and had a similar issue with the MIDI-clock. Lately I discovered, that the controller was eating up the MIDI signal for its internal sync. Maybe your controller has a setup which is eating up MIDI input or was being programed by SYSEX-commands from the Roland drum KIT? If you have a setup-tool for the Axiom-49 I would try to reset it to factory settings.

Comment: On OS X I would recommend to open the Audio-MIDI-Setup tool. With CMD-2 you can open the MIDI studio. Here you can see if your Axiom-39 and M-Audio was detected by OS X. If not, try to completely reboot the computer. If no device appears, try another USB port. I've had a slack joint in my USB-Cable once and one of the USB ports of my MAC was damaged (loose contact, too).